# writing to an Excel file in Python

Tags: python, excel, string, openpyxl

I am trying to write a string to a certain cell in an Excel file by Python. This is what I have written:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.cell(row =1, column=2).value = t1
```

However, the following error appears:

```
TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'str'>
```

How can I write a string to cell?

Comment: could you tell what's t1 in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to accomplish ?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
t1='asd'
ws.cell(row =1, column=2,value = t1)
wb.save("fileName.xls")
```

[image]
this save a file with value asd in the cell

Comment: This does indeed answer the question.